# Can iOS app pull some environment variable from enterprise MDM?

Tags: ios, mobile, environment, mdm

We have an app developed for us by a software company. We want the app to be published to the official Apple App Store, and then pull it to our enterprise internal App Store. Is is possible to have some environment variable checked at the app launch, in such a fashion that if it contains certain value, it connects to our server, and if it is launched from Apple App Store - it connects to a different server.
It could look something like this:

```
if (mdm.companyName() == "My company":
   connect to my company server
else:
   connect to something else
```

The purpose of it is that we would have one step less at launch, and the user would only have to pass the the user name and password, but not the server address.

If we have the connection to our server hard-coded into the app source, then Apple would not be able to review the app before publishing it (we would have to give them access to our server which is not an option).

Any suggestions on how to go around it would be appreciated. I was trying to get this information from here, but could not find anything: https://developer.apple.com/enterprise/documentation/MDM-Protocol-Reference.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I think it will not be possible to "pull the app to the internal enterprise app store".

AppStore apps have to be signed by your "normal" Developer Certificate, while Enterprise apps have to be signed by an "Enterprise" developer certificate.

If you really want the AppStore app to co-exist to your enterprise App, I would suggest to just create two different .ipa files

- one for the Apple AppStore, with some different server URL, which will then be reviewed etc.
- one for your internal enterprise app store, with an internal server url

So during build, you decide if you build for Apple AppStore or for Enterprise, and provide different configuration files.

Since Apple does not review enterprise apps, you can use internal URLS without any restrictions.

Comment: Thank you for your super  fast answer. We actually already did this - we can pull the app from Apple App Store and deploy it through our corporate store, but this is not the branded app we want. When they give as the branded app for us as IPA file, the APNS dosn't work :/

Comment: Well, APN _should_ work with enterprise apps as well. The thing is, you need a differt app ID for your enterprise app (and therefore have to provide different push notifications).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, but support needs to be built in to the application.

A number of MDM/EMM vendors support the [AppConfig](https://appconfig.org) standard.

Microsoft InTune isn't listed in the site, but I believe that InTune can push the required files too.

Using [Managed App Configuration](https://appconfig.org/ios/) an XML file is pushed to the device when the app is distributed from the enterprise App Store. The contents of this file is available as a dictionary in `UserDefaults` through the `com.apple.configuration.managed` key.

If this key is present then the app can extract the relevant value, such as a server address. If it isn't present then it can use a default value.